# How to remove parent/child dependency?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to draw a large circle with small circles around it. Currently the parent is the large circle with the small circles as its children. I want any circle to turn red when I hover over it but if I hover over any of the child circles the parent turns red too.

Here is my code:

```js
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var largediv = document.getElementById('large');

var div = 360 / 6;
var radius = 150;

var offsetToChildCenter = 50;

var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(largediv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes parent is square
var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
  childdiv.className = 'small';
  childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';

  var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;

  childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";

  childdiv.style.width = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  childdiv.style.height = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  childdiv.innerHTML = "Example Text"

  parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
  //largediv.appendChild(childdiv);
}
```

```css
#large {
  position: relative;
  margin: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.small {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.small:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.small:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px red;
}


/* for centering */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="large"> Example Center Text</div>
  </div>

  <script src="calc.js"></script>

</body>
```

I tried to fix this by creating another empty parent div and making the large circle a sibling of the small circles but the small circles do not center themselves around the large circle.

I am very new to html/css/js and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried running your code, and uncommented `largediv.appendChild(childdiv)`, and it was working all fine.

Comment: @YongQuan the commented line works fine but when I hover over child elements the center changes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to hover only the child element. However you can create similar effect using the sibling element

```js
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var largediv = document.getElementById('sibling');

var div = 360 / 6;
var radius = 150;

var offsetToChildCenter = 50;

var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(largediv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes parent is square
var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
  childdiv.className = 'small';
  childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';

  var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;

  childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";

  childdiv.style.width = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  childdiv.style.height = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  childdiv.innerHTML = "Example Text"

  //parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
  largediv.appendChild(childdiv);
}
```

```css
#large {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

#sibling {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: none;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

#large:hover {
  color: blue;
  background: pink;
}

.small {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 99;
}

.small:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.small:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px red;
}


/* for centering */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="sibling"></div>
    <div id="large"> Example Center Text</div>

  </div>

  <script src="calc.js"></script>

</body>
```